# Async.each final callback not firing when it is inside a deferred promise callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

Based on my research thus far, I believe I'm using async.each correctly. The bottom function addToPlaylist calls the top function getPerformances. I'm trying to figure out why the final callback in addToPlaylist isn't called and how to fix it. Thanks!

```
var getPerformances = function(playlist, performances, add){
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var tracks = [];

  async.each(performances.performance, function(performance, cb) {
    getSpotifyArtistId(performance.artist.displayName).then(function (artistId) {
      if (add == true) {
        getTopTracks(artistId).then(function (trackstoAdd) {
          tracks.push.apply(tracks, trackstoAdd);
          cb();
        });
      } else {
        //Other stuff... only looking at the true option at this point
      }
    });
  }, function(err){
    if( err ) {
      console.log(err);
      deferred.resolve(tracks);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(tracks);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is here- final callback isn't called if cb() is inside the then(). if CB is moved outside of the promise callback, finalCallback is called but of course, it is called too soon.

```
var AddToPlaylist = function (playlist, results) {
  var allSongs = [];
  var handler = function (performances, cb) {

    getPerformances(playlist, performances, true)
      .then(
      function (trackstoAdd) { // all is well!
        allSongs.push.apply(allSongs, trackstoAdd);
        //console.log(allSongs) is as expected
        cb();
      }
      ,
      function (err) { // something bad happened!
        cb(err);
      }
    );
  }
  var finalCallback = function () {
    console.log('test');
  }

  async.each(results, handler, finalCallback);
}
```

Comment: no `cb()` is called when `add === false` in `getPerformances`.

Comment: that's true, but I've actually been testing a case when it is true. I'm actually ignoring the "else" at this point. updated the code to reflect this

Comment: It doesn't look like you're handling errors thrown by `getSpotifyArtistId` or `getTopTracks`.

Comment: Thanks.. you were right on with the getSpotifyArtistId. It turned out that the Spotify api I was using was not fulfilling the promise if nothing was found in search.